# What is the scriptural source of the DHYANA SLOKA of Sri Padmanabha Swami?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, temple

[image]

[image]

What is the **scriptural source** of the dhyana sloka of Padmanabha Swami as shown in the enclosed image?

**Why is Shiva shown in Linga Form and not in His original form while all other deities are in their original form?**

**Please note that I am not interested in any local stories.**

The Question and the answer of [Is the Padmanabhaswamy idol at Trivandrum represented as worshipping Siva linga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23700/is-the-padmanabhaswamy-idol-at-trivandrum-represented-as-worshipping-siva-linga) does NOT throw any light on what I want to know. Moreover the site referred to writes that 33 crores of gods and demigods are present in the temple, whereas hinduism has only 33 types of God! I want the reference to the dhyana mantra of the deity and not wild imaginations.

Comment: If you look at the history of this temple - http://www.sreepadmanabhaswamytemple.org/history.htm  **In 1686 A.D. the Temple was almost fully destroyed in a major fire accident. Work on the re- construction of the Temple was started only in 1724.**..... **In 1730 the idol was again moved to ‘Balalaya’ prior to the renovation and reconstruction of the sanctum sanctorum. It took two years for completion. The old wooden idol was replaced by the one that we see today.** So the idol that we see today is pretty recent. Who knows whether the original idol had any Shiva linga under the hand...

Comment: @LazyLubber Most of the images on net showing Shiva Linga

Comment: Thats ok. That could be the current idol. My point is - who knows whether this was the case with the original idol?

Comment: @LazyLubber The people who saw the original idol were alive. I dont think the new idol was made without any guidance

Comment: We can only speculate :). I do not want to conclude anything without evidence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the Padmanabhaswamy idol at Trivandrum represented as worshipping Siva linga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23700/is-the-padmanabhaswamy-idol-at-trivandrum-represented-as-worshipping-siva-linga)

Comment: Shiva' s actual form is linga jyoti only....